# What is base in Linear Algebra (vector, matrix)?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For each of the following sets explain whether or not the set is/could be a basis for the space mentioned.

a) $(-x,y)$ and $(x,-y)$ for $x \not = 0$ and $y \not = 0$ in $\Bbb R^2$.

b) $(1,2,3)$, $(1,2,0)$, $(-1,2,6)$ in $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for a) What is $(-1)(x,-y)$?

Hint for b) How can you show that a set of vectors is linearly independant? What is the definition for a set of vectors to form a basis?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Are both $\lbrace (-x,y),(x,-y) \rbrace$ and $\lbrace (1,2,3),(1,2,0),(-1,2,6) \rbrace$ linearly independent?

Comment: arent those Dependent ?

Comment: @Andy: No, one set is linearly independent while other is not.

Comment: ahh right 2nd one is independent, but dependency shows what? for basis, btw still i havent understand that _base of vector_ can you explain it by simple sentence?

Comment: @Andy: you're right. So what can you conclude when a subset $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ of three elements is linearly independent?